# TypeError: find_elements_by_tag_name() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given error using find_elements_by_tag_name() using Selenium and Python

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, findelement

I'm currently running some automation testing, and it seems that the button called "Next" is not allowing me to do any action with any indication like Xpath, ClassName, or Tag_Name. What should I do in this circumstance?

```
import requests
import json
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from config import get_web_driver_options
from config import get_chrome_web_driver
from config import set_ignore_certificate_error
from config import set_browser_as_incognito
from config import set_automation_as_head_less
import time
from selenium.webdriver import ActionChains
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

URL = "https://celticonlineapp-staging.azurewebsites.net/application"

options = get_web_driver_options()
set_ignore_certificate_error(options)
set_browser_as_incognito(options)
set_automation_as_head_less(options)
driver = get_chrome_web_driver(options)

driver.get(URL)
print("We are inside of the website")

time.sleep(4)
click0 = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name("button", [1])
click0.click()
print("Button 0 Action")
```

Any recommendations, or anything that you could do differently?

Answer (score 0):

### find_elements_by_tag_name()

[find_elements_by_tag_name()](https://www.selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/webdriver_remote/selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.html#selenium.webdriver.remote.webdriver.WebDriver.find_elements_by_tag_name) accepts a name of html tag (eg: h1, a, span), finds elements by the tag name and returns a list with elements if any was found. An empty list if not.

As an example:

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')
```

---

### This usecase

If your use case is to refer to the first element of the list returned by `find_elements_by_tag_name()` your effective line of code will be:

```
click0 = driver.find_elements_by_tag_name('button')[0]
```